# Poly1305 reuse of r

Tags: cryptanalysis, finite-field, poly1305

Poly1305 uses $r, r^2, r^3$ and $r^4$.  I understand this if $r$ is a generator of the finite field.  But since $r$ can be any random non-zero number, won't its exponents be non-uniform distributed? That is, even if $r$ is chosen with uniform random over the field, $r^4$ is not uniform over the field.  Why isn't this a weakness?

Note that Bernstein's papers* use similar schemes for *any* finite field, using up to $r^8$, implying that they are acceptable for *any finite field*.

* Section 4.2 of https://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/pema-20071022.pdf uses $r$ 8 times, each with a higher exponent.

Comment: What do you mean by "up to r^8"?

Comment: @Fractalice Edited with answer

Comment: Thanks, I see 8 times but I still don't see "each with a higher exponent" there.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, modulo a prime, already $r^2$ are non-uniform - only half of the values are possible. While the computed polynomials indeed do not follow uniform distribution, the non-uniformity is bounded: each output value of the polynomial may have at most $L$ preimages (roots), where $L$ is its degree, equal to the number of blocks. Meaning that the probability may increase from $1/R$ to $L/R$, where $R$ is the number of all possible $r$ (which is $2^{106}$ in Poly1305). To get a non-negligible success probability, one has to attempt a forgery with a huge number of blocks.

Note that the output is masked by adding *AES(nonce)*. This makes blind prediction of the MAC useless. The most powerful attack here is a differential forgery attempt: given a *(message, nonce, tag)* triple, generate another triple *(message', nonce, tag')*. The same nonce removes *AES(nonce)* from the consideration in the difference $(tag' - tag)$. We "only" have to predict *poly(message') - poly(message)* for any *message* and *message'* of our choice. Which is hard since a difference of non-equal polynomials is still a nonzero polynomial of the same or smaller degree, and the probability to guess the right output is small.

This reasoning works for any finite field.

**edit:** thanks to @poncho for noticing a dangerous confusion of xor and addition over GF(p)

**edit:** in https://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/pema-20071022.pdf , Bernstein first introduces a dot-product-based MAC, i.e.. $MAC(m) = m_1r_1 + m_2 r_2 + ... + s$. The $n=8$ shares are chosen only for an illustration, since this allows only to sign messages of 8 blocks. Again, this is only done for educational reasons and to show "pure" historical constructions. Later in the paper, he replaces $r_i$ with $r^i$: this allows to avoid fully-fledged pseudorandom generation and storage of many $r$'s. Similarly, fully random $s$ can be replaced by e.g. AES(nonce).

Comment: You might want to go a bit more into the "any finite field" part of the question.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you clarify the math a bit? I understand you to be saying: If we would use 8 separate $r$ values (as Bernstein's other paper shows), you'd have a $1/R$ probability of guessing $a$.  Since we use only one $r$, and use it exponentiated $L = 8$ ways, you have a $L/R$ prob.  Why is $L$ is the _max_ exponent? I'd expect it to be the _sum_ of _all_ exponents (i.e. if max is $r^8$, $L = 15$).

Comment: "Indeed, modulo a prime, already $r^2$ are non-uniform - only half of the values are possible" This seems plausible, but I can't prove it.  Can you show how you derived it?

Comment: @SRobertJames: well, of the nonzero values, half are quadratic nonresidues modulo $p = 2^{130}-5$; those are (by definition) values that cannot be represented in the form $r^2 \bmod p$.  That is, there are no possible value $r$ for which $r^2$ are those values, and hence they have probability 0 of appearing.

Comment: "Note that the output is masked (xored) by AES(nonce)."; actually, it is added.  One thing that I observed a while back is that if you replace this addition with xor (as you wrote), high probability forgeries are quite possible...

Comment: @poncho you are right, good catch! The proof only covers GF(p) difference, while with xor AES(nonce) we have to consider the distribution of the xor difference. But do you have a concrete high probability attack in mind for this case?

Comment: @SRobertJames the polynomial computed is roughly $m_1 r^1 + m_2r^2 + ... + m_8 r^8$ ($m_i$ is the $i$-th message block). No matter how many terms, it has degree 8, so L = 8.

Comment: @Fractalice: yes, I found a differential (to both the message and the tag) that succeeded with probability either 0.25 or 0.5.  It's been a while - I'll see if I can dig it up...

Comment: @poncho I see, multiplication by -1 mod $2^{130}-5$ is very close to xoring with the all-one bitstring. So we could use the maximum encodable value $c_1=2^{129}$ and its negative $c_1'=2^{129}-5$. The XOR seems to be equal to the modulus $2^{130}-5$ with high probability.

Comment: Would the exponent be 131, it won't work!